# Unique indexes in DB2

Tags: oracle, db2

I am migrating some SQL queries from Oracle to DB2 UDB 8.

Here is the SQL query:

```
create unique index ACT_UNIQ_RU_BUS_KEY on ACT_RU_EXECUTION
(case when BUSINESS_KEY_ is null then null else PROC_DEF_ID_ end,
case when BUSINESS_KEY_ is null then null else BUSINESS_KEY_ end);
```

Does anybody know what could be a equivalent SQL in DB2 UDB 8.x?

FYI: This is an SQL query I am creating for Activiti BPM tool.

Comment: I suppose every SQL statement is a query of sorts, but many people reserve 'query' for something that retrieves data from the database, using DML (data modification language) for statements that alter the data in the database, and DDL (data definition language) for statements such as this which define how the data is stored.

Comment: Your index just takes advantage of the fact that if all the columns in the index are NULL, no entry is stored in the index. (As Leffler said, the second case expression is redundant.) You'd want to find out if DB2 supports function-based (or expression-based) indexes; if not, you may have to just make do with an index on (PROC_DEF_ID_, BUSINESS_KEY_).

Answer (score 1):

That seems to be a complicated way to build an index, and the third line looks remarkably as if it is equivalent to writing just `BUSINESS_KEY_`.  Assuming that `PROC_DEF_ID_` and `BUSINESS_KEY_` are column names, then the index seems to be on those two columns in that sequence, with the twist that if `BUSINESS_KEY_` is null, then the first column in the index is also treated as null.

There isn't a way to do that in DB2, as far as I know - at least, not in the 8.x versions.  The DB2 LUW 9.7 manual page for [CREATE INDEX](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000919.html) does not mention anything equivalent.

Comment: thanks, yes the PROC_DEF_ID and BUSINESS_KEY_ are columns. What will be the closest possible SQL DDL in DB2? Can I specify conditions in DB2 while creating an index? (I think the Oracle SQL above is doing that.)

Comment: @Ayusman: AFAICS, there isn't an easy solution in DB2.  If it were IBM Informix Dynamic Server, then I'd suggest a 'functional index', which is an index based on the result of a specified function call, where you'd write the function to return the values from the 2 CASE expressions in the Oracle example.  A quick check of the [DB2 9.7 Info Center](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp) suggests that there is no equivalent of a functional index; a quick check with a knowledgeable colleague indicates this is correct.

Comment: Johnathan is correct that DB2 for non-mainframe platforms does not allow indexes on expressions. The workaround is to add a GENERATED ALWAYS column that stores the result of the expression, and create an index on that. Even then, you would not be able to define the index as unique if the column/expression could contain NULL, since DB2 does not support "unique when NOT NULL" indexes.